# What is the minimum required access level (permission) required to move, create, remove Azure SQL elastic pool?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-server, azure-sql, azure-elasticpool

I am developing a background worker that moves database between pools, create a pool, delete a pool, etc. I couldn't find in Microsoft document what the minimum required access to do such tasks? Admin to Azure SQL Server, Contributor or anything? I also read both server and database statistics from `sys.*` databases.

Answer (score 1):

You need atleat Contributor role to perform create, delete, move, etc. related task.

A Contributor role allow to **Grants full access to manage all resources, but does not allow you to assign roles in Azure RBAC, manage assignments in Azure Blueprints, or share image galleries.**

[image]

Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor for more details.

**To read data from system tables make sure you have required role assigned on database level, e.g., db_datareader role.**